# issue with sprite.events.onInputDown.add() with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, phaser-framework

I am a new web dev and is currently working with Vue.js framework.
Decided to try out making a game with Phaser 2, and I am currently loving it!
Although i ran in to some problems with mouse events, i have no problems with key down events ;)

currently I am trying to click on an image, just to console log it out. (will want to drag later on.)
but first thing is first, I cant even get my console log out. 
here is my code, and I am using it with vue.js!
Any help will be great ! Thank you!

Below are some snippets of my code that i think will be important

```
mounted () {
  let self = this
  if (this.game == null) {
    this.game = new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, Phaser.AUTO, this.$el, {
      preload: function preload () {
        self.preload(this)
      },
      create: function create () {
        self.create(this)
      },
      update: function update () {
        self.update(this)
      },
      render: function redner () {
        self.render(this)
      }
    })
  }
}
preload () {
  this.game.load.image('pink', require(`@/assets/images/packing/pink-bg.png`))
  this.game.load.image('cat', require(`@/assets/images/packing/cat-head.png`))
  this.game.load.image('table', require(`@/assets/images/packing/table.png`))
  this.game.load.image('plate', require(`@/assets/images/packing/plate.png`))
  this.game.load.spritesheet('container', require(`@/assets/images/packing/container-set.png`), 310, 270)
  this.game.load.spritesheet('scorePlate', require(`@/assets/images/packing/kueh-set.png`), 313, 270)
}
let cat = this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'cat')
cat.height = this.game.world.height * 0.25
cat.width = this.game.world.width * 0.15

let table = this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'table')
table.height = this.game.height
table.width = this.game.width

this.game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE)

let containerBullu = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.width - (this.game.world.centerX + this.game.world.centerX), this.game.world.height / 7, 'container')
containerBullu.height = this.game.world.height * 0.55
containerBullu.width = this.game.world.width * 0.35
containerBullu.frame = 4
containerBullu.inputEnabled = true
containerBullu.events.onInputDown.add(this.listener, containerBullu)

let containerCornflake = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.width - (this.game.world.centerX + this.game.world.centerX / 1.8), -50, 'container')
containerCornflake.height = this.game.world.height * 0.6
containerCornflake.width = this.game.world.width * 0.35
containerCornflake.frame = 9
render (phaser) {
  this.game.debug.spriteInfo(this.containerBullu, 100, 100)
}
listener (containerBullu) {
  console.log(containerBullu)
},
destroyed () {
  this.game.destroy()
}
```

I hope to hear from anyone soon!
Thanks!

sincerely,
desperate and crying new front end web developer. (I was on it for 4hours. as of now. still going... )

Comment: If you try `containerBullu.events.onInputDown.add(function() {
    console.log('In onInputDown')
})` , do you see console log message?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. I added it in but my console log is not getting another. it seems the function is not going through at all.

Comment: UPDATE* 
I am able to console.log(containerBullu) , and see that the inputEnabled is TRUE.
Somehow the events.onInputDown.add() is not firing.

will update as I find out more! thanks!